# Vue.js + TypeScript component registration

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am migrating my Vue.js project to the TypeScript.
I found problem during component registration. My code looks like below:

```
import {Vue, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator'
import ScheduleCard from '../ScheduleCard/ScheduleCard.vue'

@Component({
    components: {
        ScheduleCard
    }
})
export default class ScheduleCanvas extends Vue {
    get userSchedule() {
        return this.$store.state.userSchedule;
    }

    addUserSchedule() {
        this.$store.dispatch('prepareAndAddUserSchedule');
    }
}
```

When I am trying to import this component and use in another I receiver an error that this component cannot be found.

Adding `Vue.component('schedule-canvas', ScheduleCanvas)` on the end of the .ts file did the job, but why I have to add this? As far as I know this should work without this line. Could everyone let me know why is that and what could be wrong?

UPDATE: Below code of the parent Component

```
import {Vue, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import store from './store/store'
import ScheduleCanvas from './components/ScheduleCanvas/ScheduleCanvas.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    ScheduleCanvas
  }
})
export default class Application extends Vue { }

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: Can you show the file where you are trying to use the ScheduleCanvas component? Have you tried adding ScheduleCanvas under the "components" object in the @Component decorator?

Comment: I added parent Component code.

Comment: Just wanna be sure: when that error is received, is it a runtime error (i.e. happens when you load the page in a browser), or is it a compiler error (i.e. unable to build the bundle because the path to `ScheduleCard.vue` is incorrect)?

Comment: Are you using <ScheduleCanvas/> or <schedule-canvas/> in the parent component view? The notation "{ ScheduleCanvas }" is short for "{ ScheduleCanvas: ScheduleCanvas }" so you should be using the former. To use the latter, you would have to enter "components: { 'schedule-canvas': ScheduleCanvas }".

Comment: The error is when I trying load page in a browser. I tried both ScheduleCanvas and schedule-canvas, both not working :/
The same case in ScheduleCard component working properly.